# How to setup Google Cloud Dataform git connection in a sub folder to use it in a monorepo?

Tags: github, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, monorepo, dataform

Is there a way to tell Dataform to store its files in a sub-folder within a git repository ?

We have a monorepo such as:

```
my-app/
├── server/
│   ├── package.json
│   └── ...
└── client/
    ├── package.json
    └── ...
```

And we would like to store our dataform scripts in the same repository to make it look like this:

```
my-app/
├── server/
│   ├── package.json
│   └── ...
├── client/
│   ├── package.json
│   └── ...
└── dataform/
    ├── definitions/
    ├── package.json
    ├── dataform.json
    └── ...
```

But the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataform/docs/connect-repository) only explains how to store the `definitions/`, `package.json` and `dataform.json` files at the root of the repository.
Is there another way to achieve this ?

Comment: I think managed Dataform wants the Dataform artifacts as the root attributes of the Git repository.  However, in your story, perhaps you could have two repositories ....

* my-app ... Your master repository
* my-app-dataflow - Your Dataflow repository

and use Git [Submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) to map the dataform folder to the my-app-dataflow submodule.